# SQL for Oracle to check if a constraint exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

In SQL Server I can use the SQL below to check if a constraint exists and if it's a primary key, trigger, etc.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.sysobjects 
    WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[SCHEMA].[TABLENAME]') 
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
```

What would be the Oracle equivalent because my query uses SQL Server specific tables to find the answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'CONSTR_NAME';
```

THE `CONSTRAINT_TYPE` will tell you what type of contraint it is

- R - Referential key ( foreign key)
- U - Unique key
- P - Primary key
- C - Check constraint

---

To find out if an object is a trigger, you can query `USER_OBJECTS`. `OBJECT_TYPE` will tell you if the object's a trigger, view, procedure et al.

Comment: +1 That is quite I was writing when your answer loaded up. An interesting link for the OP would be:         http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_constraints.htm